# Yii CActiveDataProvider generate SQL query

Tags: php, yii

`CActiveDataProvider` generating auto query to count total item count:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `transaction` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `partner` `partner` ON (`t`.`partner_id`=`partner`.`id`)
```

This query is slow, because contain join, how I can set manualy total count, and disable this auto query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may manualy set [total item count](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider#setTotalItemCount-detail) for CActiveDataProvider to prevent auto calculation.

```
class Model extends CActiveRecord {

    public function search(){
      $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
      // your criteria here
      $data_provider = new CActiveDataProvider($this, array('criteria'=>$criteria));
      // replace $this->count( $criteria ) with your own condition or another criteria
      $data_provider->setTotalItemCount( $this->count( $criteria ) );
      return $data_provider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try set use CActiveDataProvider->countCriteria.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider#countCriteria-detail